# Ошибка ссылающиеся на метод в приложении

Tags: android, android-studio

Столкнулся недавно с ошибкой которая довольно редко возникает, но все же

**Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago. Wait queue length: 13. Wait queue head age: 20510.9ms.)**

а ссылается все на метод который вызывается в основной активити и в основном потоке

Обьясните что означает этот набор букв пожалуйста и на что ссылаться при решении ошибки

Comment: Если решено — значит напишите ответ с описанием решения

Comment: Ошибка возникала из-за бесконечного цикла ¯\_(ツ)_/¯